# Conexão Bluetooth Arduino e Android (Java) - InputStream armazenando dados antigos

Tags: java, android, arduino

Estou fazendo uma classe em Java bem simples, apenas para simular a comunicação do Android com o Arduino via Bluetooth. A ideia é a seguinte:

O Arduino de 5 em 5 segundo vai acender e apagar um LED. Se o LED estiver aceso, a String "1" vai ser enviada à porta serial, se estiver apagado será a String "2".

Já no celular, quando o botão "Receber dados" for pressionado, um EditText deve mostrar "1" se o LED estiver aceso (que deverá ser a mensagem recebida do Arduino) e "2" se o LED estiver apagado (que deverá ser a mensagem recebida do Arduino).

O problema está no seguinte: a partir do momento que eu faço a conexão do Bluetooth entre o celular e o módulo, as mensagens do Arduino estão ficando "empilhadas" no `InputStream` (fonte de bytes), e ao apertar o botão "Receber dados" não aparece o real estado no LED ("1" para aceso e "2" para apagado), mas sim a informação que está "empilhada" no `InputStream`.

Tentando exemplificar passo-a-passo para ficar mais claro:

- Conexão Bluetooth estabelecida
- LED    LIGADO > Arduino escreve "1" na porta Serial
- ...5 segundos
- LED DESLIGADO > Arduino escreve "2" na porta Serial
- ...5 segundos
- LED    LIGADO > Arduino escreve "1" na porta Serial
- ...5 segundos
- LED DESLIGADO > Arduino escreve "2" na porta Serial
- Botão "Receber dados" apertado no celular quando o LED está DESLIGADO
- Resultado que aparece no EditText: **1**.

Ou seja, deveria aparecer "2", mas apareceu "1" porque ele era o "primeiro da fila", que o Arduino enviou para a porta Serial lááá no começo do programa.

**Finalmente, a pergunta que fica é: como posso acessar sempre o último byte que está no InputStream para receber o real estado do LED, sem tem que receber informações antigas?**

Li a documentação do Arduino (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) para tentar "limpar" os dados da porta Serial mas não encontrei nada do tipo. Também tentei algum método da classe InputStream (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) mas não tive sucesso.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda ou idéia!

Seguem os códigos:

1 - Do Arduino:

```
void setup(){

  // Começa comunicação via USB com PC
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Começa comunicação com o módulo Bluetooth, que está ligado no pino RX1, TX1
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){

  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
  Serial1.print("1");
  delay(5000);

  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  Serial1.print("2");
  delay(5000);

}
```

2 - Java/Android (O único método crucial para o problema acho que é o "ReceberDados")

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

    // Widgets do Layout
    Button conectar;
    Button desconectar;
    Button receberDados;
    EditText textoRecebido; 

    // Represents a remote Bluetooth device.
    private BluetoothDevice dispositivoBluetoohRemoto;

    // Represents the local device Bluetooth adapter.
    private BluetoothAdapter meuBluetoothAdapter = null;

    // A connected or connecting Bluetooth socket.
    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;

    private static final String endereco_MAC_do_Bluetooth_Remoto = "20:14:05:15:32:00";

    public static final int CÓDIGO_PARA_ATIVAÇÃO_DO_BLUETOOTH = 1;

    // Anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with 
    // reasonable confidence that the same identifier will never be 
    // unintentionally created by anyone to identify something else
    private static final UUID MEU_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // A readable source of bytes.
    private InputStream inputStream = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        fazerConexoesDoLayout_e_Listeners();

        verificarCondiçãoDoBluetooth(); 

    }

    public void fazerConexoesDoLayout_e_Listeners(){

        conectar =     (Button)findViewById(R.id.conectar);
        desconectar =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.desconectar);
        receberDados =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.enviarDados);

        textoRecebido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textoEnviado);

        conectar.   setOnClickListener(new Conectar());
        desconectar.setOnClickListener(new Desconectar());
        receberDados.setOnClickListener(new ReceberDados());

    }

    public void verificarCondiçãoDoBluetooth() {        

        // Get a handle to the default local Bluetooth adapter.
        meuBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Verifica se o celular tem Bluetooth
        if(meuBluetoothAdapter == null){    

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dispositivo não possui adaptador Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Finaliza a aplicação.
            finish();           

        } else {

            // Verifica se o bluetooth está desligado. Se sim, pede permissão para ligar.
            if(!meuBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){

                // Activity Action: Show a system activity that allows the user to turn on Bluetooth.

                // This system activity will return once Bluetooth has completed turning ON, or the
                // user has decided not to turn Bluetooth on.

                // Notification of the result of this activity is posted using the
                // #onActivityResult callback. The resultCode will be RESULT_OK if 
                // Bluetooth has been turned ON or RESULT_CANCELED if the user has
                // rejected the request or an error has occurred.
                Intent novoIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(novoIntent, CÓDIGO_PARA_ATIVAÇÃO_DO_BLUETOOTH);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){

        case CÓDIGO_PARA_ATIVAÇÃO_DO_BLUETOOTH:

            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth foi ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else { 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth não foi ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }       

            break;
        }
    }

    public class Conectar implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Validate a Bluetooth address, such as "00:43:A8:23:10:F0".
            // (Alphabetic characters must be uppercase to be valid)            
            if(BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(endereco_MAC_do_Bluetooth_Remoto)){

                // Get a BluetoothDevice object for the given Bluetooth hardware.
                // Valid Bluetooth hardware addresses must be upper case, in a format
                // such as "00:11:22:33:AA:BB"
                dispositivoBluetoohRemoto = meuBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(endereco_MAC_do_Bluetooth_Remoto);

            } else{ 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Endereço MAC do dispositivo Bluetooth remoto não é válido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try{

                // Create an RFCOMM BluetoothSocket socket ready to start an insecure
                // outgoing connection to this remote device using SDP lookup of UUID.
                // The RFCOMM protocol emulates the serial cable line settings and 
                // status of an RS-232 serial port and is used for providing serial data transfer
                bluetoothSocket = dispositivoBluetoohRemoto.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MEU_UUID);

                // Attempt to connect to a remote device.
                bluetoothSocket.connect();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch(IOException e){

                Log.e("ERRO AO CONECTAR", "O erro foi" + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexão não foi estabelecida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }               
        }
    }

    public class Desconectar implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(bluetoothSocket != null) {
                try{
                    // Immediately close this socket, and release all associated resources.
                    bluetoothSocket.close();

                    bluetoothSocket = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexão encerrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch(IOException e){

                    Log.e("ERRO AO DESCONECTAR", "O erro foi" + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro - A conexão permanece estabelecida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                }

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não há nenhuma conexão estabelecida a ser desconectada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }                           
        }           
    }

    public class ReceberDados implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Verifica se há conexão estabelecida com o Bluetooth.
            if(bluetoothSocket != null){

                textoRecebido.setText("");

                try{

                    // Get the input stream associated with this socket.
                    inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

                    byte[] msgBuffer = new byte[1];

                    // Reads bytes from this stream and stores them in the byte array
                    inputStream.read(msgBuffer);

                    textoRecebido.setText(new String(msgBuffer));                   

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensagem foi recebida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch(IOException e){
                    Log.e("ERRO AO RECEBER MENSAGEM", "O erro foi" + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensagem não recebida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth não está conectado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o que você precise é "limpar" os dados do **InputStream** antes de chamar o `read()`.

> O método `available()` verifica se tem "sujeira", e retorna o número de bytes que podem ser "descartados".

```
int available = inputStream.available();
if (available > 0) {
    // Cria um buffer para ler a "sujeira"
    byte[] uselessBuffer = new byte[available];

    // Lê a "sujeira"
    mmInStream.read(uselessBuffer);
}
```

Depois desse trecho de código, você faz o `read()` do dado que você quer:

```
            byte[] msgBuffer = new byte[1];

            // Reads bytes from this stream and stores them in the byte array
            inputStream.read(msgBuffer);
```

Mais informações sobre o método `available()` do **InputStream**:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: Legal, vou tentar. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Eu também passei por esta situação.
A minha solução foi semelhante ao que foi sugerido pelo Caio

O que eu fiz foi o seguinte:

- Criar um tipo de mensagem, por exemplo: um código numérico ou String, como preferir.
- Na aplicação Android, logo ao estabelecer a conexão BT, enviar esta mensagem.
- No arduino:

  - Limpar buffer até receber esta mensagem para iniciar a execucao das piscadas
  - Utilizar o flush para evitar problemas de comunicacao (opcional)

Código Arduino sugerido:

=========================================
    /* Exemplo para comunicacao entre o Arduino e o Android
     *
     * Neste caso, o arduino fica esperando receber uma mensagem para iniciar o
     * processamento.
     * E ai fica piscando o led e enviando mensagens para o android sobre o status do led
     *
     */

```
// Pino do led

#define PINO_LED 13

// Mensagem para iniciar o processamento, que a aplicacao Android vai enviar

#define MENSAGEM_INICIAR 'I' 

// Em execucao ?

boolean emExecucao = false;

//*** SETUP

void setup(){

  // Começa comunicação via USB com PC
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Começa comunicação com o módulo Bluetooth, que está ligado no pino RX1, TX1
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  pinMode(PINO_LED,OUTPUT);

  // Limpa buffer de entrada

  limpaBufferEntrada ();

}

// *** Loop de processamento

void loop(){

  // Espera receber uma mensagem do android para iniciar a execucao

  if (emExecucao) { // Execuca o processamento, neste caso piscar os leds e enviar o status para o android

    digitalWrite(PINO_LED,HIGH);
    Serial1.print("1");
    Serial1.flush(); // Aguarda o buffer de saida
    delay(5000);

    digitalWrite(PINO_LED,LOW);
    Serial1.print("2");
    Serial1.flush(); // Aguarda o buffer de saida
    delay(5000);

  } else { // Ainda aguardando o android

    leDadosSerial();

  }
}

// Limpa buffer de entrada

void limpaBufferEntrada() {

  while (Serial1.available()) {

    Serial1.read();

  }

}

// Le dados da porta serial

void leDadosSerial() {

  // Le dados da porta serial 1

  while (Serial1.available()) {

    char caract = (char)Serial1.read();

    if (caract == MENSAGEM_INICIAR) {

      //Mensagem de inicio da execucao recebida

      emExecucao = true;

     } else {

       // ignora qualquer outra entrada

        delay (50); // Uma pequena pausa, para reduzir o processamento

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função para escutar o serial de tempos em tempos, atribua o valor do serial para uma variável exemplo: "atual", essa variável guarda o valor atual no serial, logo se você não envia mais nada ao serial nem limpa ele, o valor continua lá.(limpe o serial sempre antes de usar).

Logo para saber se o valor atual é condiz com que esta no serial, que foi o ultimo valor enviado, compare os dois, se iguais, um switch para setar o pin como HIGH ou LOW.

Caso os valores não sejam iguais, ocorreu um delay, no serial, ou alguma coisa do tipo, logo não ira acionar o LED.

Answer (score 0):

Tem esse tutorial aqui [(Comunicação Bluetooth entre Arduino e Android)](http://dragaosemchama.com.br/2016/04/comunicacao-bluetooth-entre-arduino-e-android/). Eu demorei um pouco pra entender como o código funciona, mas depois de dar uma bela estudada consegui moldar meu app em cima do código mudando só as parte que precisava, espero que ajude, boa sorte ai hehe